# Convergence and boundedness of double indexed sequence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space.  Assume $(z_{n,m})_{n,m}$ is a sequence in $X$ and $x\in X$ such that

$z_{n,m}\rightarrow^{m\rightarrow \infty} z_n'$ and $z_{n'}\rightarrow z'$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Then, why is it that $(z_{n,m})_{n,m}$ is bounded up to subsequence?

Argument: As $m\rightarrow \infty$, $z_{n,m}$ goes to $z_n'$ so for each $n$, $(z_{n,m})_{m}$ is bounded. Now $z_{n'}\rightarrow z'$, $(z_n')_{n}$ is bounded.

That is there exists an $M>0$ such that $|z_n'|\leq M$.

So, $|z_{n,m}|\leq |z_{n,m}-z_n'|+|z_n'|\leq M +|z_{n,m}-z_n'|$

Now $|z_{n,m}-z_n'|\rightarrow 0$ as $m\rightarrow \infty$, so $|z_{n,m}-z_n'|$ is bounded by a constant $C_n$ for all $n$.

Why $C_n$ bounded above by something independent of $n$?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't true.  Take $X = \mathbb{R}$, $z_{n,1} = n$, and $z_{n,m} = 1$ for $m > 1$.  Then $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} z_{n,m} = 1$, which clearly converges to $1$, but $z_{n,m}$ is unbounded.

---

If we want to show the existence of a bounded subsequence, note that for all $n$ there exists $M = M_n$ such that $|z_{n,m}-z_n'| < \frac 12$ for all $m \ge M_n$.  Now, we have that $|z_{n,M_n}| \le |z_n'| + |z_{n,M_n} - z_n'| < |z_n'| + \frac 12 < C$ for some constant $C$.

Comment: I meant up to subsequence, sorry!

Comment: @monoidaltransform What do you mean by "up to subsequence?"

Comment: I meant some $n_k$ such that $x_{n_k,m}$ is bounded

Comment: Just $x_{n_k,m}$?  Not $x_{n_k,m_k}$?  Because this example still works otherwise: $\sup_{n_k,m} x_{n_k,m} \ge \sup_{n_k} x_{n_k,1} = \sup_{n_k} n_k = \infty$.

Comment: Sure, could you write an answer for when $n_k,m_k$?